# useEffect throw warning for dependecy

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown menu which has a controlled state. If the user changed the dropdown value and if the input is not empty, fire a function passed from other component.

```
export default ({ triggerChange, inputVal }) => {
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputVal) {
      triggerChange(dropdown);
    }
  }, [dropdown]); // this line throw a warning

  const handleChange = e => {
    setDropdown(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-browser-cusyb)

Error

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'inputVal' and
>   'triggerChange'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.
>   If 'triggerChange' changes too often, find the parent component that
>   defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback.
>   (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

Answer (score 7):

Add those to the dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (inputVal) {
    triggerChange(dropdown);
  }
}, [dropdown, inputVal]);
```

This will only re-run the effect if either `dropdown` or `inputVal` values change.

**For `triggerChange`:**

if `dropdown` changes frequently, use `useCallback` hook.

```
// Parent.js
const memoizedTriggerChange = useCallback(
  () => {
    triggerChange(dropdown);
  },
  [dropdown],
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (inputVal) {
    memoizedTriggerChange();
  }
}, [inputVal]);
```

**EDIT**

based on the OPs codesandbox

```
// index.js
const triggerChange = useCallback(() => {
  console.log("call api");
}, []); // not depending on inputVal to prevent firing if inputVal changes

// AnotherComp.js
useEffect(() => {
  triggerChange(dropdown);
}, [dropdown, triggerChange]);
```

Comment: adding inputVal as dependency doesn't throw away the warning https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-browser-cusyb

Comment: if I add inputVal as dep, very stroke will fire triggerChange which I don't want.

Comment: what is useCallback for? your code make triggerChange trigger when the app first load.

Comment: @Hanz when you pass down a function as prop, you need to memoize it (i.e ensure that the function isn't "new" which will cause re-render)

Comment: @Hanz `useEffect` is like `componentDidMount`. So if you want to prevent `triggerChange` on first load, add a condition to prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (inputVal) {
      triggerChange(dropdown);
    }
  }, [dropdown]); // this line throw a warning
```

In this piece of code, if you notice, `inputVal`, `triggerChange` and `dropdown` are variables and they are dependencies to useEffect hook because useEffect gets triggered whenever any change is made to any of the aforementioned dependencies.

To satisfy the basic working principle of useEffect hook, we should pass those depdencies in useEffect's array parameter.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputVal) {
      triggerChange(dropdown);
    }
  }, [dropdown, triggerChange, inputVal]);
```

Comment: if you put triggerChange as dependencies, every keystroke will call api https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-browser-cusyb which is not what I want